# Does ArrayList implement the behaviour of the List ADT?

Tags: java, abstract-data-type

I have read a lot of articles and watched videos about Abstract Data Types, and I have one question I haven't been able to find answered.

By reading about ADTs I understand the List ADT in Java provides us with a set of behaviours, and then we can use for example ArrayList or LinkedList to implement these behaviours in different ways. Is this correct?

I'm sure it has been answered somewhere in between the lines but I hope somebody can actually answer me as I have read numerous articles and I'm still not sure.

I have gotten to a point where the more videos I watch or articles I read, the more I start second-guessing what I have learned so far about ADTs in Java.

Comment: There's not much to say about this other than "yes". The class `ArrayList` implements the `List` interface, which is Java's representation of the "list" abstract data type.